# Parsing senteces from a txt file to a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, increment

this is driving me crazy. I'm trying to parse from a txt file every sentence (that is all characters between dots) and insert each sentence into an array. The end goal is to have a multi dimensional array with each sentence as single array.
I managed to reach a point where I think it should work but I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error from the line `numOfRow++`

```
void parseRows(FILE* file){
    int c;
    int numOfRow = 0;
    int numOfChar = 0;
    int numOfRows = countNumOfRows(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // Reset file pointer position to the beginning
    char **rows = malloc(numOfRows*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i=0; i < numOfRows; i++) rows[i] = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));

    while ((c=fgetc(file))!= EOF) {   
        if (c != '.') {
            rows[numOfRow][numOfChar] = c;
            numOfChar++;
        } else {
            rows[numOfRow][numOfChar] = '\0';
            numOfRow++;       // This is throwing the error              
            numOfChar = 0;            
        }
    }
    printOutput(rows, numOfRows);
}
```

If I comment out that line the program overwrites every line on the first array and I get only the last sentence as result so I know it's working.
What am I missing?

Complete code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define USAGE "USAGE: ./huffman <textFile.txt>\n"

FILE* openFile(char[]);
void parseRows(FILE*);
int countNumOfRows(FILE*);
void printOutput(char**, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE* fd;
    if (argc != 2) printf("%s", USAGE);

    fd = openFile(argv[1]);
    parseRows(fd);
}

FILE* openFile(char* file){
    FILE* stream;
    stream = fopen(file, "r");
    return stream;
}

int countNumOfRows(FILE* file){
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c=fgetc(file))!= EOF) {   
        if (c == '.') i++;
    }
    printf("numero di righe %d\n", i);
    return i;
}

void parseRows(FILE* file){
    int c;
    int numOfRow = 0;
    int numOfChar = 0;
    int numOfRows = countNumOfRows(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // Reset file pointer position to the beginning
    char **rows = malloc(numOfRows*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i=0; i < numOfRows; i++) rows[i] = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));

    while ((c=fgetc(file))!= EOF) {   
        if (c != '.') {
            rows[numOfRow][numOfChar] = (char)c;
            numOfChar++;
        } else {
            rows[numOfRow][numOfChar] = '\0';    
            numOfRow += 1;               
            numOfChar = 0;            
        }
    }
    printOutput(rows, numOfRows);
}

void printOutput(char** matrix, int rows){
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        printf("%s", matrix[i]);
    }
}
```

Example of input file textFile.txt:

```
Any text that contains more than one sentence.
This Should get parsed and return a 2 dimension array with every sentence as single array.
```

Comment: Please show an example of input file as well as a [MCVE].

Comment: I think that's exactly what I've done? numOfRow is initialized at 0 and increased in the else statement every time you find a sentence

Comment: Why not use `fgets`? You're trying to read an entire line at a time.

Comment: I didn't know what to put as size... How would I use fgets to split between dots?

Comment: Well you could tokenize the line that's returned on `.`... I did misunderstood though so that might not be worth the effort. As for the size, why not 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your countNumOfRows() function counts the dots in a file, and you use that number to malloc space for your array.  However, there are likely more characters beyond the last dot and before EOF (e.g. a CR or LF or CRLF), so you can easily write past the end of your malloc'd memory.

Try:

```
return (i + 1)
```

at the end of countNumOfRows() and see if that eliminates the segfault.

Comment: The error is still there. I  tried to allocate `char **rows = malloc(1000*sizeof(char*));` and used a txt file with 2 rows just to be sure and the error is still there.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you!